# Azure Logic App FTP Connector not running for files modified before the current date

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I am working on FTP Connector of the Azure Logic App and it is working fine if I upload a file with today's last modified date.
But FTP connector is not triggered for files that are modified before the current date. 
I have found in the trigger history that the trigger is **skipped** and **Status code 202** is being returned.
Kindly suggest me a solution so as to trigger the FTP Connector whenever any file (even if is modified a year ago) is added on the FTP.

Comment: what do you mean ? The trigger works when you upload a new file. not for existing files

Answer (score 5):

The FTP connector maintains a trigger state, which is always the last date it ran or the date it was created (for the very first run). Thus, it only triggers if there are messages with a modified date which is later than that trigger state.

A potential solution is not to use the FTP trigger, but the recurrent trigger, and then use the FTP connector action `list files in folder`. This will give you all existing files there. Then you can get the content for each, and if your processing succeeds, you can delete the file.

HTH